# How to inject a third party lib into angular-fullstack via Webpack

Tags: angularjs, express, webpack, angular-google-maps, angular-fullstack

I have generated a new angular-fullstack project using the Yeoman generator generator-angular-fullstack.
Everything seems to be running fine.

Now I simply want to be able to use angular-google-maps lib in my angular-fullstack project.
http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use

How can I add it to the the angular-fullstack so that the lib is injected into the main controller and can be used everywhere?

Maybe it's due to my lack of familiarity with the Webpack and the way it is setup at angular-fullstack.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: are you using ES6 syntax ? if so just import if not you need to require your lib. Let me know what syntax you are using I will write a guide here.

Comment: angular-fullstack (github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) uses ES6 with import syntax. Thank you very much for writing a guide, it can potentially help many others as well.

Comment: Any help... anyone? Thanks